# elementaryOS update Horus 7.1 (to version 6.5) Macbook Air : WLAN no longer available in Network

Tags: wifi

is it possible to fix Networkproblem, emerge WLAN-connection in Horus 7.1 (vers.6.5)?

Thanks

Comment: problem fixed, thanks to : https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/posts/13721/revisions

Answer (score 0):

Wifi-Problem resolved, thanks to: https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/users/578/lemonslice